# Conversion to Alamofire 4 breaks Alamofire.Request extension

Tags: alamofire, swift3

I had this little extension on Alamofire 3, it was used to get certain tokens and data from the default response.

```
public extension Alamofire.Request {

    private func authorizationHandler(queue: dispatch_queue_t? = nil, completionHandler: (NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse?, NSData?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Self {
        return response { (req, res, data, error) in

            if let headers = res?.allHeaderFields {

                if let id = headers["x-uid"] as? String {
                    oHTTPEnvironment.x_uid = id
                }

                if let authToken = headers["x-access-token"] as? String {
                    oHTTPEnvironment.currentMutableToken = oHTTPEnvironment.nextMutableToken
                    oHTTPEnvironment.nextMutableToken = authToken
                }
            }

            dispatch_async(queue ?? dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                completionHandler(req!, res, data, error)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

And now in Alamofire 4 and Swift 3 it get's an error on the "*return response { (req, res, data, error) in*"
The error is:

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'HTTPURLResponse'

I even tried to do:

```
private func authorizationHandler(queue: DispatchQueue? = nil, completionHandler: (NSURLRequest, HTTPURLResponse?, NSData?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Self {

    return response { resp in
        debugPrint(resp)
    }
}
```

But it gives the same error.